# How to embed an Angular app in another website?

Tags: angular, embed

There is a file ts with the following import:

```
import dictJsonRu from '../../assets/i18n/ru_RU.json';
```

After build the browser tried to find this file on my local machine using relative path.

How to make this path absolute?

I have trie this:

```
import dictJsonRu from 'src/assets/i18n/ru_RU.json';
```

My ts config is:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./"
```

Error is:

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/O/Desktop/Projects/ka/assets/i18n/ru_RU.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

Also I tried this:

```
  "paths": {
      "@assets*": ["src/assets/*"]
   }

import dictJsonRu from '@assets/i18n/ru_RU.json';
```

If to set `<base href="/" />` in html file I get this error:

```
 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/assets/i18n/ru_RU.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

My html file looks like this:

```
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="http://remoteserve/mp.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to find file relative this `http://remoteserve/mp.js/ssets/i18n/ru_RU.json.`

I use IIS, probably I can set web.config to say where to loook files when main.js is required in client?

Comment: try `import dictJsonRu from 'assets/i18n/ru_RU.json';`   --> I guess there is `"baseUrl": "./src",` in you "tsconfig.json"

Comment: See my question again, I posted config ts

Comment: So there is a difference between environments!? It works in "dev", but not in "prod" environment. Is that correct?

Comment: No I get this file not from envirement, I just import it as usual ts file

Comment: I have main.js output file that is placed on hosting. I create a index.html page on my localhost where placed this remote main.js file.

Comment: You should put everything from the ".dist/" folder on your hosting server, not just the "main.js" file

Comment: I have put everything ,problem in paths not in files

Comment: main.js and others files are placed on remote server

Comment: All right, if everything worked as expected it should work now, wenn you acces the index.html on the remote server in your browser

Comment: No it does not work, could we move in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233748/discussion-between-coverbase-and-tino).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way,

```
   "paths": {
        "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"]
    },


import dictJsonRu from '@assets/i18n/ru_RU.json';
```

Comment: I have tried, see above, problem is that I run index.html from localhot, but bundle.js I request from remote server

Comment: You mis spelling  `/` after @assets

Comment: Does not work anyway, MY html looks like this:

`<body>
       <app-root></app-root>
      <script src="http://remoteserve/mp.js"></script>
</body>`